# Find a character in pipe separated file c#

Tags: c#

I have a pipe separated file and I need to replace a character with blank space

For example:

```
MANGO |"APP | LE "| GRAPE
```

Though APPLE is a single word, the extra pipe symbol in between the word is causing failure.

I need a c# code to find the pipe symbol that comes after `|"` and replace it with blank space ("")

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The `|` in `| GRAPE` also comes after a `"`. You need a decent CSV parser, don't write your own unless that is homework.

Comment: @bommelding it's different. before apple is a |" and before GRAPE is a "|.

Comment: @SebastianKilb -  So you think there can only be 1?  Exactly 1?

Comment: what you have to do is, loop through each character and compare the current character and the one after it. If it is |" you continue looping and search for the next | and replace it with "". Then you continue with searching for |"

Comment: Use regular expressions. In your given string double quotes is a quantifier.

Comment: Your 'blank space' looks a lot like you actually want the empty string.

Comment: Why can't you use a simple `string.Replace()` or `Regex.Replace()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex,

```
string input = " MANGO |\"APP | LE \"| GRAPE";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[A-Za-z ]\|[A-Za-z ]", "");

Console.WriteLine(input);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Edit:
The above regex is for checking | with leading and trailing spaces. The Regex

`string result = Regex.Replace(input, "(\"\\S+\\s+)\\|(\\s+\\S+\\s+\")", "$1$2");`

will search for the | within quotes for the given string in question

Comment: This does rely on spaces around the `|` and it isn't limited to inside  `"`

Comment: @bommelding Yes I agree. Thanks for pointing out..  string result = Regex.Replace(input, "(\"\\S+\\s+)\\|(\\s+\\S+\\s+\")", "$1$2"); will be the answer for problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right

> I need a c# code to find the *pipe symbol* that comes after `|"` and
>   replace it with *blank space* (`""`)

means that you want to *remove* all pipe symbols `|` which are within quotations `" ... "` (quotation starts with `"`, ends with `"` if there is quoatation mark within quotation it should be *doubled*)

I suggest implmenting **FSM** - *Finite State Machine* with two states: within quotation or not:

```
private static string PipeRemove(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  bool inQuot = false;

  foreach (char c in value) {
    if (c != '|' || !inQuot) // add any char except pipe within quotation
      sb.Append(c); 
    // else // uncomment this if you want space ' ' instead of pipeline '|'
    //   sb.Append(' ');

    if (c == '"')            // states changing
      inQuot = !inQuot;
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}

...

string test = "MANGO |\"APP | LE \"| GRAPE";

string result = PipeRemove(test);

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
MANGO |"APP  LE "| GRAPE
```

Please, notice that even if `|` has been removed you have to remove spaces that break `APPLE` word into two

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is likely much more complex than you are making it look, but here is a regex that should work for your given example:

```
(\|"[^|]*?) \| (.*?"\|)
```

Replace with `$1$2`

For example:

```
// input: MANGO |"APP | LE "| GRAPE |"hello  | world "|

string input = "MANGO |\"APP | LE \"| GRAPE |\"hello  | world \"|";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\|""[^|]*?) \| (.*?\""\|)", "$1$2");

// result: MANGO |"APPLE "| GRAPE |"hello world "|
```

[Try it out online here](https://regex101.com/r/71saNo/1/)